# How to avoid fatal error or unknown error in powershell on windows server 2016

Tags: node.js, powershell, windows-server

Sometimes i get unknow error in powershell on windows server 2016, every time this error have random behavior, but every time is "Fatal error", like on screenshot.

[Screen_Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7HAZ.png)

```
Unknown type: 541

#
# Fatal error in, line 0
# unreachable code
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000007BD8BFF1F0
```

What is that and how to fix this? I launch node.js on this server

Memory leak? Disc error?

P.S. on Linux server i dont have any errors, but i need to launch my code on Windows server 2016. Sorry if my question was stupid or is a duplicate.

Comment: Without example code this is impossible to diagnose, with the type error it could be a class issue though.

Comment: I have this errors on random time on Windows server 2016. I dont have problems like in my question on server with Linux(Ubuntu). On server with Windows Server 2016 i run only my script, but i need to run my code on server with Windows Server 2016 because this server have very good hardware and i dont have any opportunity for change system. I think this some of hardware problems like errors in memory.
Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that problem spot - CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Does in your code you've setup something like :

```
$ErrorActionPreference = Stop
```

This will stop your process at any errors; anyway the best practice is to use the try/catch block to handle any error and , at least, display where and what is the error message.

In your case, I suspect there is a bad memory access or conflict with something but without more details it's pretty difficult.

Do you use in your script the try and catch block ?

Comment: Yes in my code i use try catch, but i dont stop my code on any errors. On server with ubuntu i never get this errors, i think this is something with windows server, but i dont know how to check what wrong.
Server with Linux(Ubuntu) is another server with another hardware.
PS Thank you man for answer